# Passing a parameter to a variable in code C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to use this program, but I would like to be able to pass a parameter where:

```
DeleteOnReboot(@"C:\test.txt");
```

"C:\Text" is

So I could call consoleapp.exe /C:\test2.exe

So I would have a variable in code e.g.

```
DeleteOnReboot(@"%VARIABLE%");
```

---

Full Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool MoveFileEx(string
lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName, int dwFlags);

public const int MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT = 0x4;

public static void DeleteOnReboot(string filename)
{
if (!MoveFileEx(filename, null,
MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT))
    Console.WriteLine("Failed");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
DeleteOnReboot(@"C:\test.txt");
Console.ReadKey();
}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pull the file path, name from string[] args.

DeleteOnReboot(args[0]);

Or something similar and call it like this: consoleapp.exe C:\test2.exe

Answer (score 2):

just use the `args` array that is in the entry point of your program (`Main`)

Example:

`DeleteOnReboot(args[0]);`

Comment: He already did, just replace `DeleteOnReboot(@"C:\test.txt");` with `DeleteOnReboot(args[0]);`

Comment: Well, I guess you'd need to change `consoleapp.exe /C:\test2.exe` to `consoleapp.exe C:\test2.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the contents of your args variable in main? this is where the parameters are passed to and how you can access them in your console app.

Comment: You dont "set" it, the args are already available, check the declaration of main, they are there for you to use.